# Unexpected result with Constraints - Database SQL

Tags: mysql, database, constraints

Trying to figure out why this constraint doesn't work as expected and attempting to find solution.

A description of tables and attributes below:

```
Table Hotel
hotel_id - primary key - INT(5)

Table Room
room_id - primary key - INT(5)
hotel_id - primary key - INT(5)
room_type - VARCHAR(25)

Table RoomType
room_type - primary key - VARCHAR(25)
hotel_id - primary key - INT(5)
type_description - VARCHAR(100)
price - INT(5)
```

So the constriants:

```
room.room_type references roomtype.room_type
room.hotel_id references hotel.hotel_id
roomtype.hotel_id references hotel.hotel_id
```

So the desired result of this would be that for all the hotels will have room types that are unique to them. Then hotels will also have rooms that are linked to a roomtype. So example data for these would be:

```
Hotel:
hotel_id
1
2


Room:
room_id     hotel_id     room_type
1           1            Single
2           2            Double

RoomType:
room_type  hotel_id    type_description   price
Single     1           Random             500
Double     2           Random             500
```

So if I tried adding this row to the Rooms I would expect it not to work due to constraints. As for hotel_id 1 there is no roomtype Double in the roomtypes table. This still works and doesn't get stopped by the constraint.

```
Room
room_id   hotel_id  room_type
3         1         Double
```

So how would you do this?

Comment: I am guessing that you are thinking that a constraint is the same as a reference or key. It won't work if the constraints are properly constructed. Are you able to use the mysql shell and capture the output of "show create table Hotel" and all the other tables as well so that we can examine the definition of the relations between the tables.

Comment: i am assuming that since this question is tagged as mysql that you have these tables populated as described.

Comment: Why do you have hotel_id on roomtype? Also, will all room types be the same price for different hotels...dont think so...